# Different ways in which we can create a class, which can not be sub classed (Extended)?

Tags: java

Of course by making class as a final we can not able to extend it. Apart from these, are there any other ways in which we can create a class which is not extendable?

Comment: Could you define "..or making it as immutable"? Making class final is one of steps of making class immutable. Maybe you mean "making its constructors private"?

Comment: Correct.@Pshemo. So all together here i wants to know apart from making class as final are there any other ways except details mentioned by @Daniel O. in which we ensure that even at compile time also that this is not extendable.. ?

Comment: @road2victory :  I have added few ways to prevent the class from being Subclasses. you can see my answer below. Hopefjlly it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all the constructors in the class `private` (or give them default access, if you are only concerned with subclasses in another package), including a `private` no-argument constructor. Any classes which attempt to inherit from such a class will not compile, even if there is no attempt to create objects of the subclass. You can still provide the ability to instantiate such a class with a static `getInstance(arguments)`-type method.

The clearest and cleanest way to prevent a class from being extended, however, is to declare the class as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the ways, we can prevent a class from being subclassed.

1. Declare the class `final` and no other class can sub class it. **This is the best approach, to prevent extension of a class**. `final` keyword is ment for this purpose.
2. Do not expose any non private Constructor. In case there is no constructor defined then define the `default constructor` and declare it `private`. Note that this in such a case inner classes can still extend the outer enclosing class. Hence its better we declare the class as final.  We have classes like `String.java` , `Integer.java` etc, these classes can not be subclassed and these are declared `final`.
3. Throw runtime exception from all the constructors. This will dis allow the object creation. You can have a private constructor, without code to throw exception, creating the objects (may be in an public static method). This will not give compile time but will throw exception during run time when object of sub-classed is tried to be created. Sub classes can call the constructors from may be a static method and wrap it in a try catch block. Hench this is not as clean as above two.

Immutability is more than just declaring a class `final` or restricting the constructors to just private scope. You need to protect any mutable state as well. Above answer only intends to solve the problem of having a class which can not be sub classed.